# Как задать MSS на сетевой интерфейс?

Tags: linux, mtu

Хоть я и ставлю на сетевой интерфейс MTU, MSS автоматически не подставляется под  MTU.
Как сделать фиксированный MSS для определенного интерфейса?

Comment: `Хоть я и ставлю на сетевой интерфейс MTU, MSS автоматически не подставляется под MTU.` — что-то мне не верится... как это определил?

Comment: Мне в прошлый раз в ответаз сказали что MSS не подстраивается, + еще прочитал что в openvpn такая же проблема иногда встречается

Comment: что подразумевал тот кто отвечал в прошлый раз лучше спросить у него, но о MSS стороны должны договариваться во время установки соединения и оно должно вполне корректно устанавливаться на основе локального MTU, если это не так, то в системе какие-то куда более серьёзные проблемы... жёстко переопределить его можно например средствами `iptables`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSS устанавливается в момент установления TCP соединения, его можно менять посредством iptables, у меня сработало так:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -o e+ -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 800
```

Где `e+` это шаблон захватывающий все ethernet интерфейсы, можно поменять на конкретный интерфейс. `-I OUTPUT 1` вставляет правило в начало цепочки, в чем можно убедится выполнив `iptables -nvL OUTPUT --line-numbers`. Удалить: `iptables -D OUTPUT 1`. Это все будет работать только до перезагрузки, чтоб правила фильтрации применялись при старте нужно уже найти документацию по конкретному дистрибутиву.

Comment: Так же стоит рассмотреть опцию `--clamp` вместо установки конкретного значения. А конкретное значение ставить только в случае, если clamp не помог